# Javascript looping over array and checking logical statements

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to run a series of logic tests on an array. Each array contains 1 ID number and 1 item.  I need to check the following: If ID number 1 appears in an array it must contain either shoe or sock (anything other than shoe or sock return false) and their must be at least one occurrence of [1, sock] and [1, shoe]. ID 1 does not need to occur, the later only applies once it occurs.  Likewise the same condition for ID 2. I wanted to give my function an array of objects that tell it what to look for - the var f in my function.  My logic here works fine if there is only 1 object in the array, but once I add more it fails.

I think I am going wrong with flattening the item arrays.   Is there a better way to do something like this, perhaps with reducing and or mapping?

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function d(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}


var test_data = [[1,'shoe'],[1,'sock'], [2, 'apple'], [2, 'pear']];

function checker(array){
    var f = [{id_num: 1, item: ['shoe', 'sock']}, {id_num: 2, item: ['apple', 'pear']}];

    var mm = true;
    var inLine;

    var valids = function(obj){
        vlist = [];
        _.forEach(obj, function(item){
            vlist.push(item.item);
        });
        return _.flatten(vlist);
    };

    _.forEach(f, function(obj){
        _.forEach(obj.item, function(zone){
            inLine = false;
            _.forEach(t, function(line){
                if(_.contains(valids(f), line[1])){
                    if(_.contains(line, obj.id_num) && _.contains(line, zone)){
                        inLine = true;
                    }
                } else { inLine = false; }
            });
            mm = mm && inLine;
        });
    });
    d(mm);
}

checker(test_data);
```

an Example of the expected outcome would be if test_data is [[1,'shoe'],[1,'sock']]. The expected outcome should be True since 2 does occur.  The tests only apply if the value appears...

Answer (score 0):

My version of this:

```
var f = [{id_num: 1, item: ['shoe', 'sock']}, {id_num: 2, item: ['apple', 'pear']}];

//Reduces our schema to an object using the IDs as keys
var f_new = f.reduce(function(sofar, curr){ sofar[curr.id_num] = curr.item; return sofar},{})


//Helper. Checks if the item is permitted
function valid(item){
      var possible_items = f_new[item[0]+""]
      return _.contains(possible_items, item[1])
}


//Reduces the test data to the same format that f_new
function test_data_occurences (test_data) {
    return test_data.reduce(function(sofar, curr){    
        if(!valid(curr)){throw "Invalid item "+curr}

        var items = sofar[curr[0]]
        if(items===undefined){
            sofar[curr[0]] = [curr[1]]
        }else{
            items.push(curr[1])
        }
        return sofar
    },{})
}

//Does the actual work
function array_valid(array){
    try{
        var array_occurences = test_data_occurences(array)
        //Loops through each ID
            _.each(array_occurences, function(values,id ){
                //Gets the possible values
                var possible_values = f_new[id]
               //Checks if all possible values are contained as actual values
               var contains_all = _.all(possible_values, function(val){return _.contains(values,val)})
               if(!contains_all)throw("Not all values are contained for ID "+id)
            })
        }
    catch(err){
        console.log(error)
        return false
    }
    return true
}


array_valid([[1,'shoe'],[1,'sock'], [2, 'apple'], [2, 'pear']])

array_valid([[1,'shoe'], [2, 'apple'], [2, 'pear']])
//Not all values are contained for ID 1

array_valid([[1,'shoes'],[1,'sock'], [2, 'apple'], [2, 'pear']])
//Invalid item 1,shoes
```